# DJANGO -ImportError: No module named pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination

I clone this [FairyBBS](https://github.com/ericls/FairyBBS) project . When runserver in console,error message appears as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named pagination
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!

Comment: This's the answer.  We must install the dependencies in requirements.txt and only then we can run server

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the dependencies in requirements.txt. The best way to do that is to use virtual environments.

Please read http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ to get an idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

Please install this as

```
pip install django-simple-pagination
```